# Forward declaration mess

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am creating a multithreaded class method that needs to call `compute`.

```
void compute(const Me::MyClass<T>& c1, Me:: MyClass<T>& target,std::size_t start);

namespace Me{
    template<typename T> class MyClass{

        computeMultiThreaded(){

            MyClass<T> target = MyClass();

            std::size_t n_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

            std::vector<std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t>> parts = split_job(n_threads, number_jobs);
            std::vector<std::thread> threads;

            for (std::size_t ti = 0; ti < n_threads; ti++)
            {
                // , parts[ti], minCol, this, m2, returnMatrix));
                threads.push_back(std::thread(compute,parts[ti]));
            }
        }
    }
}


void compute(const Me::MyClass<T>& c1, Me:: MyClass<T>& target,std::size_t start){
...
}
```

Now when I try to compile this with `compute` defined after `MyClass`, `Me::MyClass` is not known in the first definition of `compute`. When I delete the first declaration, `compute` will not be known when creating the thread?

How can I resolve this catch 22?

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'Me'
```

Comment: Does 

    using Me::MyClass;

help?

Comment: It's a simplified example of a larger project...

Comment: Yes because you use `Me` before declaring it. so the namespace must be declared before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know about the existence of `Me::MyClass` when it reads the declaration of `compute`. So all we need to do is tell it that the class exists!

```
namespace Me {
    template<typename T> class MyClass;
}
```

you can later define `Me::MyClass` like so

```
template<typename T> class Me::MyClass {
// insert your class definition
};
```

The first snippet is a class declaration, the second is a class definition.

Answer (score 5):

Declare `MyClass` before the declaration of `compute`. And `compute` needs to be a function template if you want it to have arbitrary `MyClass<T>` parameter types.

```
namespace Me
{
    template<typename T>
    class MyClass;
}

template<typename T>
void compute(const Me::MyClass<T>& c1, Me:: MyClass<T>& target,std::size_t start);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "forward-declare" the namespace and including forward declaration of your class then later do your job correctly:

```
namespace Me {
    template<typename T> class MyClass;
    template <class T>
    void compute(const MyClass<T>& c1, MyClass<T>& target, std::size_t start);
}
```

Then later:

```
//template<class T>
//void compute(const Me::MyClass<T>& c1, Me::MyClass<T>& target, std::size_t start); // Correct but it is already declared in namespace "Me"
```

Now the definition:

```
namespace Me {
    template<typename T> class MyClass 
    {
        void computeMultiThreaded() { // I added void here so you should add a return type
            MyClass<T> target = MyClass();

            std::size_t n_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

            std::vector<std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t>> parts = split_job(n_threads, number_jobs);
            std::vector<std::thread> threads;

            for (std::size_t ti = 0; ti < n_threads; ti++)
            {
                // , parts[ti], minCol, this, m2, returnMatrix));
                threads.push_back(std::thread(compute, parts[ti]));
            }
        }
    }; // you missed also the semicolon in your example
}

template <class T>
void compute(const Me::MyClass<T>& c1, Me::MyClass<T>& target, std::size_t start) {

}
```

I wish this works for you.